# definition of dense sets

Tags: general-topology

I have an exercise in analysis about continuous functions over a dense subset, but I don't know where to start because I don't know what a dense set is.

I did some research about dense sets and I got that it is the closure, but I am not sure if the source is credible. Is a dense set the closure of this set? Can someone please explain why is it like that?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dense_set (Checked, that it is a good source for this definition)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A subset $A$ of a topological space or metric space $X$ (for instance $A\subset\mathbb R$) is dense if the closure $\overline A$ of $A$ is equal to $X$. For instance, in $\mathbb R$ (or any metric space), this is equivalent to the condition that for any real number $r\in\mathbb R$, you can find a sequence $r_n\in A$ such that $r_n\to r$.

Comment: Thank you that was helpful

Comment: @Harry Reed thank you for the nice answer you provided. I have a question with regard to this answer, In the definition of denseness, we always say subset $A$ for example is dense with respect to $X$. What does it mean for a set like $Y$ to be dense? (Does denseness need to be defined with respect to some other set?)